# Get width of image in jQuery via passed parameter location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to get the dimensions of an image via `jQuery` or even vanilla `JavaScript`, but not one that is already *in* the page, an image location which is passed via a parameter.

Example:

```
myFunction('images/myImage.png');
```

When that path is passed into the JS function - is there a way to get the images dimensions at all?

**Please note the differences in this question and other similar questions that ask how to get the dimensions for the image on the page; it is not a duplicate.**

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate question. You can clearly see my question is different to the one linked.

Comment: It *is* the same question. It's just that the answer isn't what you'd hoped.

Comment: @isherwood Ummm, no it is *not*. An image on a page is NOT the same as an image path being passed in via a parameter; if it was then you would be able to use the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this: (although it's javascript)

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript/626505#626505)

Comment: Just got around to trying this out and it works well. Accessed the image width via `img.src` as I didn't need the `onload` stuff. Though apparently this question is a dupe lol.... but a different answer specific to my query solved my issue, fancy that lol - thanks man!